# How to set UISearchBar to safeAreaLayoutGuide programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have UISearchBar in the UINavigationController. The search bar appears good in portrait but in a landscape, it appears to half of screen. It doesn't cover the full width.

[image]

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (navigationController?.view.bounds.size.width)!, height: 64)

view.addSubview(searchBar)
let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following two lines of code:

```
searchBar.autoresizesSubviews = true
searchBar.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
```